# Draggable div moving 2px even though it's snapped to 10px

Tags: javascript, html, math, interact.js

The following code creates a draggable 40px rectangle inside a 400px grid (using [Interact.js](http://interactjs.io/)):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="live-demo">
    <div id="grid-snap"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var element = document.getElementById('grid-snap')
var x = 0
var y = 0

interact(element)
  .draggable({
    snap: {
      targets: [
        interact.createSnapGrid({ x: 10, y: 10 })
      ],
      range: Infinity,
      relativePoints: [ { x: 0, y: 0 } ]
    },
    restrict: {
      restriction: element.parentNode,
      elementRect: { top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 1, right: 1 }
    }
  })
  .on('dragmove', function (event) {
    x += event.dx;
    y += event.dy;

    event.target.style.webkitTransform =
    event.target.style.transform =
        'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';
  });
```

**CSS:**

```
.live-demo {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #e8e9e8;
}

#grid-snap {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #29e;
  color: #fff;
}
```

For some reason, the square moves an initial 2px when it's dragged for the first time. This doesn't happen when `createSnapGrid()` is set to 30px for x and y.

Not sure if this is a coding or math problem. How to modify the code (or CSS) to eliminate that initial 2px movement?

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/nq5zz27j/4/

Comment: It's not doing it for me.  What browser/version are you using?

Comment: @Ageonix Chrome Version 48.0.2564.116 (64-bit). I'm running Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: @Ageonix It happens to me with Firefox too. You have to drag the square very slowly.

Comment: Oh nevermind, I see what you mean now.  It's not snapping equally as you drag it.  That first snap is tiny (2px) then it jumps to what it should be?

Comment: @Ageonix Yes, exactly.

Comment: Well I haven't had any luck.  I added a debugger line in the .on('dragmove' event handler and confirmed that event.dx and event.dy both start at 2 the first time you move the box.  I tried stepping backwards through the interact code to see what/why that is being set to 2, but I can't seem to find it.  Also tried getting around this by setting your initial values to -2, but that only works when the script is first ran.  After that it allows the box to move outside its bounds.  Sorry I couldn't be more help!

Comment: @Ageonix That's all right. I think it has to do with math (if you change the pixels of all the elements you get a point where everything snaps correctly). Let's see if a math genius shows up!

Answer (score 1):

It is something to do with the math.  When you set the relativePoint, it is defining where the grid will snap to.  So choosing x: 0, Y: 0 will use the top left corner of your object.  As to why x: .8 and y: .8 is the answer. I don't have a scientific answer as to why this is (still working on that part).

But if you change

```
relativePoints: [ { x: 0, y: 0 } ]
```

to

```
relativePoints: [ { x: .8, y: .8 } ]
```

It will do what you are looking for I believe.  Let me know if that is what you meant.

jfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nq5zz27j/5/